# jQuery - slideToggle animation not smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to make divs below links to slide up and down animated on link click, but the animation is not smooth at all, on slide up it just jumps the final distance. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div>
<a href="#" id="may2016" class="month_name"><h2>May 2016</h2></a>
                <div class="archive_links" style="display:none;">
                    <p>Hello, 30. May 2016. 17:33</p>
                    <p>New One, 22. May 2016. 11:14</p>
                    <p>Third, 17. May 2016. 04:30</p>
                </div>
</div>
<div>
            <a href="#" id="april2016" class="month_name"><h2>April 2016</h2></a>
                <div class="archive_links" style="display:none;">
                    <p>Hello, 30. May 2016. 17:33</p>
                    <p>New One, 22. May 2016. 11:14</p>
                    <p>Third, 17. May 2016. 04:30</p>
                </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.archive_links {
            background:rgba(255,255,255, .15);
            padding:5px;
        }

        a.month_name {
            text-decoration:none;
            color:white;
            transition:color .4s ease;
        }

        a.month_name:hover {
            color:#c7c7ee;
            transition:color .4s ease;
        }
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#may2016").on('click', function() {
            $(this).next(".archive_links").slideToggle(1000);  
        });

        $("#april2016").on('click', function() {
            $(this).next(".archive_links").slideToggle(1000);  
        });
    });
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rqkt58L1/74/).
Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I see it fine. The only detail is the little "jump" at the beginning. This happens because the margins of the `p` appear immediately when jQuery sets `display` to `block` in the target. You should try to remove the margins or to put the `p` inside a `div` and animating the `div` instead.

Comment: Click on the May 2016 link and notice the jump of the April 2016 link while animation is making first div disappear. I tried removing margins, didn't help.

Comment: That's what I've explained in the answer.

Comment: Yes, but p elements are not being animated, the div with the class archive_links holding them is being animated. I tried removing margins on p and div element, didn't help. Can you try and make a jsFiddle of what you are thinking?